# Browser recognition in jquery

Tags: jquery, css

Trying to force a certain css on div in ie. So far only jquery left.
Used this code, but it didn't do anything. Where is my mistake?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($.browser.msie){
  $(".cartwrap").css('display','none');
  }
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: A better approach than browser maker detection is to use feature detection where you detect the actual capability difference that causes you to branch your behavior based on a capability versus a browser manufacturer.

Answer (score 2):

According to jQuery Website:

> *Contains flags for the `useragent`, read from `navigator.userAgent`. **This property was removed in jQuery 1.9** and is available only through the `jQuery.migrate` plugin. Please try to use feature detection instead.*

If you are using **jQuery Version >= 1.9**, please use the `jQuery.migrate` plugin.

Comment: Adding to that, this is a good feature detection plugin if that's the route you choose: http://modernizr.com/